How to resize android box partition
I have a android box and want to resize its sub partition
Here are infos:
cat /proc/partitions
major minor  #blocks  name
7        0     230448 loop0
179        0   30535680 mmcblk0
179        1       4096 mmcblk0p1
179        2      65536 mmcblk0p2
179        3    1146880 mmcblk0p3
179        4       8192 mmcblk0p4
179        5       8192 mmcblk0p5
179        6      24576 mmcblk0p6
179        7       8192 mmcblk0p7
179        8       8192 mmcblk0p8
179        9       8192 mmcblk0p9
179       10      16384 mmcblk0p10
179       11      16384 mmcblk0p11
179       12      16384 mmcblk0p12
179       13      16384 mmcblk0p13
179       14       2048 mmcblk0p14
179       15      32768 mmcblk0p15
179       16     262144 mmcblk0p16
179       17     131072 mmcblk0p17
179       18    1310720 mmcblk0p18
179       19     131072 mmcblk0p19
179       20     524288 mmcblk0p20
179       21    3145728 mmcblk0p21
179       22   23451648 mmcblk0p22
179       96       4096 mmcblk0rpmb
179       64       4096 mmcblk0boot1
179       66       4095 mmcblk0boot1p2
179       32       4096 mmcblk0boot0
179       33       4095 mmcblk0boot0p1
cd /dev/block/
ll
total 0
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          1000 May 14 07:29 ./
drwxr-xr-x   15 root     root          5260 May 14 07:12 ../
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            10 May 14 07:11 179:0 -> ../mmcblk0
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            13 May 14 07:11 179:1 -> ../bootloader
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             8 May 14 07:11 179:10 -> ../param
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             7 May 14 07:11 179:11 -> ../boot
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             6 May 14 07:11 179:12 -> ../rsv
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            11 May 14 07:11 179:13 -> ../metadata
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             9 May 14 07:11 179:14 -> ../vbmeta
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             6 May 14 07:11 179:15 -> ../tee
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             9 May 14 07:11 179:16 -> ../vendor
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             6 May 14 07:11 179:17 -> ../odm
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             9 May 14 07:11 179:18 -> ../system
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            10 May 14 07:11 179:19 -> ../product
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            11 May 14 07:11 179:2 -> ../reserved
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            11 May 14 07:11 179:20 -> ../CE_FLASH
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            13 May 14 07:11 179:21 -> ../CE_STORAGE
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             7 May 14 07:11 179:22 -> ../data
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             8 May 14 07:11 179:3 -> ../cache
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            15 May 14 07:11 179:32 -> ../mmcblk0boot0
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            14 May 14 07:11 179:33 -> ../bootloader0
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             6 May 14 07:11 179:4 -> ../env
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             7 May 14 07:11 179:5 -> ../logo
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            11 May 14 07:11 179:6 -> ../recovery
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            15 May 14 07:11 179:64 -> ../mmcblk0boot1
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            14 May 14 07:11 179:66 -> ../bootloader1
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             7 May 14 07:11 179:7 -> ../misc
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             7 May 14 07:11 179:8 -> ../dtbo
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            11 May 14 07:11 179:9 -> ../cri_data
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            14 May 14 07:11 179:96 -> ../mmcblk0rpmb
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             8 May 14 07:11 7:0 -> ../loop0
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             8 May 14 07:11 7:16 -> ../loop2
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             8 May 14 07:11 7:24 -> ../loop3
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             8 May 14 07:11 7:32 -> ../loop4
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             8 May 14 07:11 7:40 -> ../loop5
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             8 May 14 07:11 7:48 -> ../loop6
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             8 May 14 07:11 7:56 -> ../loop7
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             8 May 14 07:11 7:8 -> ../loop1
parted /dev/mmcblk0
GNU Parted 3.6
Using /dev/mmcblk0
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) p free
p free
Error: /dev/mmcblk0: unrecognised disk label
Model: MMC BJTD4R (sd/mmc)
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 31.3GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags:
(parted) print
print
Error: /dev/mmcblk0: unrecognised disk label
Model: MMC BJTD4R (sd/mmc)
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 31.3GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags:
(parted) quit
quit
parted /dev/CE_STORAGE
GNU Parted 3.6
Using /dev/CE_STORAGE
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) print
print
Model: Unknown (unknown)
Disk /dev/CE_STORAGE: 3221MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags:
Number  Start  End     Size    File system  Flags
1      0.00B  3221MB  3221MB  ext4
(parted) quit
quit
CoreELEC:/dev/block #  resize2fs -p /dev/block/179:21
resize2fs 1.47.0 (5-Feb-2023)
The filesystem is already 786432 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!
Now i want to increase mmcblk0p21 size to higher (take size from mmcblk0p22).
As above infors, 179:21 -->/dev/CE_STORAGE, it is block mmcblk0p21
Thanks!
I dont know how to resize, just get information.
